# When I use Momentjs always get same time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

When I use follow statements, I always get `2013-12-10 00:12:13`.

What's the problem?

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
```

Comment: you are getting month in place of minute because of MM instead of mm

Answer (score 0):

MM is for month and mm for minute so use `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`